# $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln n)^p}$ converge value

Tags: calculus

There's $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln n)^p}$, $p \in \mathbb{R}$. For what values p converge? Notice n=2 at the beginning. Since it's to be decreasing and always >0, I think integral testing is good. So I calculate it, I had final answer is $p>0$ converges. Yes or no?

Comment: If $1/n$ does not decay fast enough, what makes you think that $1/\ln n$ will?

Comment: $n^\epsilon >> \log n$ as $ n \rightarrow \infty$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, and also $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} 1/n$ diverges, so your series will not converge for any value of p.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $ p\le 0$ then

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln(n))^p}\ne 0$$
$\implies $ the series diverges.

If $ p>0 $, observe that

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{(\ln(n))^p}=+\infty$$

$$\implies \frac{\sqrt{n}}{(\ln(n))^p}>1$$
for $ n $ large enough.

$$\implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<\frac{1}{(\ln(n))^p}$$

$\implies $ the series is divergent by comparison test of positive series.

So, your series is never convergent.

Comment: I would assume that for $p>0$ a proof of the limit is required.

Comment: @user If $ p>0$, it is clear the general term goes to zero.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If $ p>0 $ then $\lim 1/ln^p(n)=0$.

Comment: And how from this fact follows that the series diverges?

Comment: @user No, it diverges by comparison test as i said in my answer.

Comment: And I said that this requires a proof... You cannot expect that OP knows that this limit is $+\infty$.

Comment: If OP were good in computing limits he would not ask this question. You can estimate his skills from the result of "integral testing".

Comment: @user I hope this will help him .

Comment: It may help him with this homework but probably not generally.